Debugging errors in the oath2client and google-api-python libraries
I'm trying to run some code that uses the oauth2client and google-api-python-client libraries:
def get_authenticated_service():
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS, scopes=SCOPES)
  return build(
      API_SERVICE_NAME,
      API_VERSION,
      static_discovery=False,
      credentials=credentials,
      developerKey=API_KEY)

def validate_query_job(yt_music_analytics, title, query):

  #Validate query before creating a QueryJob.
  validate_req = {"query": query}
  
  try:
    yt_music_analytics.contentOwners().validateQuery(
          contentOwner=CONTENT_OWNER, body=validate_req).execute()
    
  return True
    
  except HttpError as e:
    print(e)
    wrerror(e)
    return False



service = get_authenticated_service()
validate_query_job(service, query_title, query_text):

with a query like SELECT 1 AS x
and where SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS is a global variable to a json file. At the moment running this code I get the use the correct credentials file or a credentials file that is completely wrong, so I'm not sure if the error is with loading the credentials or with the service account I'm trying to use. I'm wondering if there are other functions I can use in these libraries to debug this or potentially get a more detailed error
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtubemusicanalytics.googleapis.com/v1/contentOwners/xxxxx_xXXX_XXXXX_XXXX:validateQuery?key=xxxxxxxxx&alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller does not have permission">

